# Server Autoinstall and Partitions

Tags: server, partitioning, subiquity, autoinstall

I'm learning about the cloud-config-ish autoinstall tool [subiquity](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity) and I keep running into a problem where the autoinstall works, but it won't follow my configuration for the `storage:` section.

Here's my autoinstall config (except for username, hostname, password hash and SSH key):

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  refresh-installer: { update: yes } # Check for updated installer
  storage:
    # ESP + boot + swap + zil placeholder + root
    layout: { name: direct }
    config:
      - type: disk
        match:      # select largest ssd...
          size: largest
          ssd: true
        id: ssd0    # ...and call it ssd0
        ptable: gpt # use gpt partitions on ssd0
        wipe: superblock
      - type: partition # create partitions on ssd0
        number: 1
        id: efi-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 256M
        flag: boot        # uefi partition needs boot flag
        grub_device: true # and must be the grub device?
      - type: partition
        number: 2
        id: boot-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 768M
      - type: partition
        number: 3
        id: swap-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 128G
        flag: swap
      - type: partition
        number: 4
        id: zil-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 128G
      - type: partition
        number: 5
        id: root-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 256G
      - type: format # format partitions on ssd0
        id: efi-format
        volume: efi-partition
        fstype: fat32 # ESP gets FAT32
        label: ESP
      - type: format
        id: boot-format
        volume: boot-partition
        fstype: ext4
        label: BOOT
      - type: format
        id: swap-format
        volume: swap-partition
        fstype: swap # swap
        label: SWAP
        flag: swap
      - type: format
        id: root-format
        volume: root-partition
        fstype: xfs # / (root) gets ext4, xfs, btrfs
        label: ROOT
      - type: mount # mount formatted partitions on ssd0
        id: root-mount # / (root) gets mounted first
        device: root-format
        path: /
      - type: mount
        id: boot-mount # /boot gets mounted next
        device: boot-format
        path: /boot
      - type: mount
        id: efi-mount # /boot/efi gets mounted next
        device: efi-format
        path: /boot/efi
  identity:
    hostname: foo
    username: bar
    password: $6$<snip>
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    allow-pw: false
    authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAA<snip>
  packages:
    - build-essential
    - git
    - python3-pip
    - tasksel
    - zfsutils-linux
```

As you can see from the `storage:` section, I'm putting in a few partitions (all GPT, no MBR on this build!):

- a FAT32 UEFI system partition at `/boot/efi`
- an ext2 `/boot` partition
- a swap partition
- a placeholder partition for a ZFS intent log (to be added later, after autoinstall)
- an XFS root partition

The Ubuntu autoinstaller seems to pass validation, because I get the proceed-with-autoinstall yes/no, it runs, and at the end I have a bootable system with ZFS installed and everything. **However, it ignores my partition scheme** and instead just creates a FAT32 EFI partition and an Ext4 root partition. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, here, or how I can track down *why* it's validating, but ignoring my `storage:` configuration?

Comment: A question for whom ever makes that tool I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for autoinstall file is not great

EITHER:

use layout: direct and let it automatically try to figure out what your partitioning should be
OR
do a config: section with your desired setup

If you do both layout and config in the storage section... it will only use the layout and ignore the config section